# Timber & WordPress: How to get the ACF term name for each item within Global Options

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I have a FAQ's page that displays items that I've setup in WordPress > Global Options. Everything works fine, except I would like to get the taxonomy term name for each one of these items.  I've tried looping through the FAQs to gather the term ID using the code below, however, the term name outputs the same term name for each item.

page-faq.php

```
if ($faqs) {
    // Create the array structure with array[group][faq]
    foreach ($faqs as $faq) {
        //using category IDs from FAQs to create groups
        $grouped_faqs[$faq['tax_category']][] = $faq;
    }
    //loop through each group created
    foreach ($grouped_faqs as $faqs) {
        $context['grouped_faqs'] = $grouped_faqs;

        //then loop through each faq in the group
        foreach ($faqs as $faq) {
            //Convert term ID to term name
            $term_id = $faq['tax_category'];
            $term_name = get_term($term_id) -> name;
            $context['term_name'] = $term_name;

            //output the faq details
            $context['faqs'] = $faqs;
        }
    }
}
```

page-faq.twig

```
{% for faq in group %}
   {% set category = faq.tax_category.name %}
   <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">{{ faq.faq_question }} - {{ faq.tax_category }}, {{ term_name }}  </a>
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
         {{ faq.faq_answer }}
      </div>
   </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here?

I tried using the code below to get the name of each item using the ID, but it doesn't work.

```
$term_name = get_term($term_id) -> name;
```

Comment: You are just overwriting your variables over and over again

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).